# Also search substrings in Area 51's proposal search

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, search

e.g. searching "electro" yields nothing, you have to type "electronics" or "electronic" and will get disjunct search results

**edit** possibly related bug: [Why is the bicycles proposal shown when searching for phys?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62405/why-is-the-bicycles-proposal-shown-when-searching-for-phys)

Comment: Yes, please. I was just about to enter this request as well. The current search is pretty poor - it only hits exact text matches.

Comment: The Ajax search on Area 51 is completely pointless. I begin typing a word, like "Philos" when I am searching for "philosophy" and it flickers and flackers and then it says "no results". So I give up searching for philosophy since I assume it's not there. But then I go back and find if I type the whole word "philosophy" into the box it appears.

May I ask, what is the point of this? Surely if it is an Ajax system which responds to user input, it should have enough brains to try to predict that I might not have finished typing the whole word.

Comment: @Tobias - how can someone get the bounty - I assume only by *solving* the issue, right?

Comment: @Mark: On meta a bounty is also used as "advertisement". But yes, solving this and posting an answer will be awarded with the bounty. Alternatively, I'll also award to a good workaround, some greasemonkeying, or (in the case of disagreement, which in this case here might not happen) a good argumentation why the feat-req should *not* be implemented

Comment: @Tobias: OK, thanks for the clarification. Let's hope this gets *fixed*, not argued away. (It's currently easier to use a site specific search in Google than the built in search. And really, how hard can it be to implement?)

Comment: @Tobias (and others) - you might be interested in my related question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64930/automatically-suggest-similar-proposals-for-area-51-site-suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area 51 search now matches prefixes, so "bicyc" will match "bicycles", "electro" will match "electronics", etc.

Comment: thanks, that is more intuitive now :)