# Should a specialised proposal be merged into a more general one even if it has more followers?

Tags: support, area-51, definition-phase

[My discworld proposal ("Ook!")](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6511/ook?referrer=hrKcR89412YN5QfMOt5KEg2) may turn out to be too specialised, but it has currently more followers than [the fantasy proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15712/fantasy?referrer=LQnOfXUTiholaRLwFFF1-A2) but would make a good subset using a [discworld] tag. So should I close it or leave that decision to the followers? I mean, does that number indicate the desire for a more specialised site or may they just not know about the more general one?

Same question for [The Simpsons](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2786/the-simpsons?referrer=jqvZ0enlJ1IN5QfMOt5KEg2) VS [Animated Series](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3494/animated-series?referrer=0KoguuhDZTAN5QfMOt5KEg2).

Comment: +1 in spirit for having a Discworld proposal.  I am going to lurk the heck out of that when it gets into public beta.  (I'm not expert enough to commit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single correct answer to this question.  Some proposals are too broad (extreme example: "Everything," AKA Yahoo! Answers) while other proposals are too narrow (extreme example: "Sonic the Hedgehog, Green Hill Zone, Act 2").  The system is designed to let people naturally build communities of things that are the right size (not-so-extreme example: "Gaming").  Worst case scenario, some tinkering can happen during or immediately after beta.

In your specific case, it might not hurt to cross-advertise a bit between Discworld and Fantasy, but I suspect that Fantasy is a bit too broad and Discworld is popular enough that it'll be able to support itself.

I definitely wouldn't pull a proposal out from under a large number of followers; in addition to making them angry and confused, it'll probably be ineffective, since someone will just repropose it.