# Populate a "related" list on Area 51, à la the other SE sites

Tags: feature-request, area-51, related-questions

Didn't see this asked for before.

When commenting on a question on any of the *running* SE sites, if a link to another question on the same site is added, it will go into the Related Questions box on the right.

Can this be done on Area 51, too? For example, when duplicates (or likely duplicates) are flagged on a new proposal, it would be handy if that would create a Related box on both proposals, so that proposals are easier to hash-out.

Comment: I think this is a **duplicate** of my question: Automatically suggest similar proposals for Area 51 site suggestions, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64930/automatically-suggest-similar-proposals-for-area-51-site-suggestions

Comment: @Mark Not quite. From the second paragraph, this is actually regarding the "Linked" section functionality so that if I'm looking at one proposal, I can see other proposals linked to it (such as likely duplicates). "Related" is auto-populated, and would be what your proposal is looking for.

Comment: @Grace Note: oops, you're right, thanks.